# How to search Vuetify Data-Table with item's other value

Tags: datatable, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My Vuetify datatable items is a JSON object array like this

```
[
  {
    name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
    calories: 237,
    fat: 9.0,   
    price: 30,
    description: 'something other aaa bbb ...'
  },
  {
    name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
    calories: 621,
    fat: 12.5,
    price: 43,
    iron: '1%',
    description: 'someting other ccc ddd ...'
  }
]
```

datatable only set headers [ name, calories, fat, price ], so it can't see the description or other value, description I want to show in a expend div, when I input text to filter item, how can let to search description to filter item
Any idea how to do that ?

Thanks so much, awesome community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:custom-filter` prop. Details [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#custom-filtering)

```
:custom-filter="customFilter"

methods: {
  customFilter(value, search, item) {
    return !!search && (item.name.includes(search) || item.description.includes(search))
  }
}
```